# imap_open show message body as plain text

Tags: php

I am using imap_open in PHP but the message body is showing like:

```
<html xmlns:v=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml\" xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\" xmlns:w=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word\" xmlns:m=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\">
<head>
<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=us-ascii\">
<meta name=\"Generator\" content=\"Microsoft Word 14 (filtered medium)\">
<!--[if !mso]><style>v\\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
o\\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
w\\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
.shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
</style><![endif]--><style><!--
/* Font Definitions */
@font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
    panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Tahoma;
    panose-1:2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Verdana;
    panose-1:2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4;}
/* Style Definitions */
p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {margin:0cm;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:\"Times New Roman\",\"serif\";}
a:link, span.MsoHyperlink
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:blue;
    text-decoration:underline;}
a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:purple;
    text-decoration:underline;}
p.MsoAcetate, li.MsoAcetate, div.MsoAcetate
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    mso-style-link:\"Balloon Text Char\";
    margin:0cm;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:8.0pt;
    font-family:\"Tahoma\",\"sans-serif\";}
span.EmailStyle18
    {mso-style-type:personal-reply;
    font-family:\"Calibri\",\"sans-serif\";
    color:#1F497D;}
span.BalloonTextChar
    {mso-style-name:\"Balloon Text Char\";
    mso-style-priority:99;
    mso-style-link:\"Balloon Text\";
    font-family:\"Tahoma\",\"sans-serif\";}
.MsoChpDefault
    {mso-style-type:export-only;
    font-size:10.0pt;}
@page WordSection1
    {size:612.0pt 792.0pt;
    margin:72.0pt 72.0pt 72.0pt 72.0pt;}
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
--></style>
```

...this continues

here is the code i am using.

```
//try to connect
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect: ' . imap_last_error());
//grab emails
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');
//if emails are returned, cycle through each...
if($emails) {
    //put the newest emails on top
    rsort($emails);

    //for every email...
    foreach($emails as $email_number)  {
        //get information specific to this email
        $header=imap_headerinfo($inbox,$email_number);
        $structure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox,$email_number);
        $from = $header->from[0]->mailbox."@".$header->from[0]->host;

        $toaddress = array_shift($header->to);
        $toaddress->mailbox."@".$toaddress->host;
        $replyto=$header->reply_to[0]->mailbox."@".$header->reply_to[0]->host;
        $datetime=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$header->udate);
        $subject=$header->subject;

        //get message body
        $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, 1.2);

        if(base64_decode($message, true)) {
            //message body if base64 encoded
            $message = base64_decode($message);
        } else {
            //message body is not base64 encoded
            $message = $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, 1);
        }

        $message = strip_tags($message);

    }
}
```

I have added the if statements to see if the message body is base64 encoded and if it is to decode it but it still displays as above sometimes. Other times it is showing as plain text but with huge line breaks.

Is there a way i make the whole message body plain text?

Answer (score 4):

try `$msg = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,1.1);`
instead of `$msg = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,1.2);`

found some more information on this topic on http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchbody.php#89002:

imap-fetchbody() will decode attached email messages inline with the rest of the email parts, however the way it works when handling attached email messages is inconsistent with the main email message.

With an email message that only has a text body and does not have any mime attachments, imap-fetchbody() will return the following for each requested part number:

- (empty) - Entire message
- 0 Message header
- 1 - Body text

With an email message that is a multi-part message in MIME format, and contains the message text in plain text and HTML, and has a file.ext attachment, imap-fetchbody() will return something like the following for each requested part number:

- (empty) - Entire message
- 0 Message header
- 1 MULTIPART/ALTERNATIVE
- 1.1 - TEXT/PLAIN
- 1.2 - TEXT/HTML 2 - file.ext

Now if you attach the above email to an email with the message text in plain text and HTML, imap_fetchbody() will use this type of part number system:

- (empty) - Entire message
- 0 - Message header
- 1 - MULTIPART/ALTERNATIVE
- 1.1 - TEXT/PLAIN
- 1.2 - TEXT/HTML
- 2 - MESSAGE/RFC822 (entire attached message)
- 2.0 - Attached message header
- 2.1 - TEXT/PLAIN
- 2.2 - TEXT/HTML
- 2.3 - file.ext

Answer (score 1):

am using `fMailbox` class to fetch emails ,see this link for usage of fmailbox

http://flourishlib.com/docs/fMailbox

configuring fmailbox is simple

```
<?php 
require_once('flourish/fCore.php');
require_once('flourish/fEmail.php');
require_once('flourish/fMailbox.php');
 $this -> mailbox = new fMailbox($emailType, $emailHost, $emailUsername, $emailPassword);
 $messageses = $this -> mailbox -> listMessages();
foreach ($messageses as $messages) {
            $messageinfo[] = $this -> mailbox -> fetchMessage($messages['uid']);
}
?>
```

and it will all the details related to email

```
array(
    'received' => '28 Apr 2010 22:00:38 -0400',
    'headers'  => array(
        'received' => array(
            0 => '(qmail 25838 invoked from network); 28 Apr 2010 22:00:38 -0400',
            1 => 'from example.com (HELO ?192.168.10.2?) (example) by example.com with (DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA encrypted) SMTP; 28 Apr 2010 22:00:38 -0400'
        ),
        'message-id' => '<4BD8E815.1050209@flourishlib.com>',
        'date' => 'Wed, 28 Apr 2010 21:59:49 -0400',
        'from' => array(
            'personal' => 'Will Bond',
            'mailbox'  => 'tests',
            'host'     => 'flourishlib.com'
        ),
        'user-agent'   => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.9) Gecko/20100317 Thunderbird/3.0.4',
        'mime-version' => '1.0',
        'to' => array(
            0 => array(
                'mailbox' => 'tests',
                'host'    => 'flourishlib.com'
            )
        ),
        'subject' => 'This message is encrypted'
    ),
    'text'      => 'This message is encrypted',
    'decrypted' => TRUE,
    'uid'       => 15,
    'text'      =>'The plaintext body',
    'html'      =>'The HTML body'
    'attachment'=>'if any as array'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

First check the structure [map-fetchstructure](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchstructure.php) of the message in question.
May be it is empty with attachement or something embedded or forworded email... etc.

You can use the function bellow to separate the message in nested array of sub items and select the item you need:

[source:](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchbody.php#89002)

```
function create_part_array($structure, $prefix="") {
    //print_r($structure);
    if (sizeof($structure->parts) > 0) {    // There some sub parts
        foreach ($structure->parts as $count => $part) {
            add_part_to_array($part, $prefix.($count+1), $part_array);
        }
    }else{    // Email does not have a seperate mime attachment for text
        $part_array[] = array('part_number' => $prefix.'1', 'part_object' => $obj);
    }
   return $part_array;
}
// Sub function for create_part_array(). Only called by create_part_array() and itself. 
function add_part_to_array($obj, $partno, & $part_array) {
    $part_array[] = array('part_number' => $partno, 'part_object' => $obj);
    if ($obj->type == 2) { // Check to see if the part is an attached email message, as in the RFC-822 type
        //print_r($obj);
        if (sizeof($obj->parts) > 0) {    // Check to see if the email has parts
            foreach ($obj->parts as $count => $part) {
                // Iterate here again to compensate for the broken way that imap_fetchbody() handles attachments
                if (sizeof($part->parts) > 0) {
                    foreach ($part->parts as $count2 => $part2) {
                        add_part_to_array($part2, $partno.".".($count2+1), $part_array);
                    }
                }else{    // Attached email does not have a seperate mime attachment for text
                    $part_array[] = array('part_number' => $partno.'.'.($count+1), 'part_object' => $obj);
                }
            }
        }else{    // Not sure if this is possible
            $part_array[] = array('part_number' => $prefix.'.1', 'part_object' => $obj);
        }
    }else{    // If there are more sub-parts, expand them out.
        if (sizeof($obj->parts) > 0) {
            foreach ($obj->parts as $count => $p) {
                add_part_to_array($p, $partno.".".($count+1), $part_array);
            }
        }
    }
}
```